# How to add scripts in HTML file passing through network?

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle, web

how to add JavaScript file to every HTML document that is passing through your network ?

Comment: Define "your network" - do you have full control of all traffic, including the types of encryption allowed?

Comment: Hint: You shouldn't ask "Is it possible?" but rather "How is it done?" questions. Unless a "yes" or "no" is all the answer you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a transparent proxy could do this. And it is actually done:

> [Code injection: A new low for ISPs](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2925839/net-neutrality/code-injection-new-low-isps.html)
>
> ... Comcast and other carriers are inserting their own ads and notifications into their customers’ data streams

See also [Injecting Javascript In HTML Content Using MITM Proxy](http://pankajmalhotra.com/Injecting-Javascript-In-HTML-Content-Using-MITM-Proxy/) on how you could do this yourself.